# Match the next pattern which is less than the previous match

Tags: regular-expression, patterns

I've got a file with QR-code lines and I want to `grep` for only those whose subsequences *do not increase in length*. Example:

This one is good because the next sequence is less or same as previous:

```
####### ###### ### ### ## # # #
```

This one is wrong:

```
### ## ## ### ### ### ###### ##
```

I started off like this:

```
egrep "[^#](####)+[ ]+(##)+" qr.txt
```

but then I realised it's going to be impossible to continue..

Comment: I updated your question to help clarify the requirement - do you mean that each chunk of #'s should have no more than (same as, or fewer) #'s than the previous chunk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
grep -vE '(^| )(#+) .*\2#' <<END
####### ###### ### ### ## # # #
### ## ## ### ### ### ###### ##
END
```

```
####### ###### ### ### ## # # #
```

Comment: Nice, but I think he wants the opposite, so `grep -v ...`.

Comment: yes. i think so too. i think maybe *(since it is clearer now)* you can drop the `#` after `\2` - if `\2` is found again at all the sequence doesn't decrease. `\2#` only finds the increase.

Comment: Very neat solution +1, but I think you should invert the match with `-v`.

Comment: @mikeserv, the requirements clearly state "the next sequence is *less or same* as previous" is "good" -- `\2#` is required

Comment: that's a good point - i contest its clarity considering the previous paragraph requires sequences which decrease in length. either way, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{l=length($1);for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if(length($i)>l){next};l=length($i)}}1' file
```

- `l=length($1)` sets the varibale `l` to the length of the first field.
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` loops trough all fields starting at the second.
- `if(length($i)>l` if the length of that field is greater than the length of the last field:

  - `next;` skip to the next line.
- `l=length($i)` set the `l` variable for the next iteration.